# create folder with current date and time as suiffix

Tags: batch-file

Could somebody help me with my batch file to create a folder in specific location where the folder name should have date and time added suffix to its name:

eg., Folder Name-> Backup_15_3_2018_04:53

I am using the below code but getting syntax error in the `mkdir` statement

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

set "datestamp=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%" & set "timestamp=%HH%%Min%%Sec%"
set "fullstamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%:%Min%:%Sec%"

echo datestamp: "%datestamp%"
echo timestamp: "%timestamp%"
echo fullstamp: "%fullstamp%"

mkdir "D:\Backup\DB_Backup-%fullstamp%"
pause
```

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask] a Good Question.

Comment: added the code which is giving syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the characters `\`, `/`, `:`, `*`, `?`, `"`, `<`, `>`, or `|` in file or folder names. Change the format of `fullstamp` so that there are no prohibited characters.

Comment: works perfectly when i changed the fullstamp which were containing - , : and replaced with ( _ , . ) thank you so much

Comment: If this solved the problem for you, you should accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark to the left of it.

Comment: @Mohan, it had nothing to do with the hyphen or comma.  Jeff explained which character was causing your problem.  The **colon**!